# How to listen to all callbacks from the server to client in SignalR?

Tags: javascript, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

To register a callback for a specific method in SignalR (JavaScript), you can do the following:

```
hubConnection.on("MyMethod", (...) => { ... });
```

However, is it possible to be able to listen to *all* methods and to get all arguments?

Comment: Please check [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0): JavaScript clients call public methods on hubs via the `invoke` method of the HubConnection. And, to receive messages from the hub, define a method using the `on` method of the HubConnection. SignalR determines which client method to call by matching the method name and arguments defined in `SendAsync` and `connection.on`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so because you have to register all of your callbacks before starting the connection. This example from the docs shows this.

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```